# How to get the data from Firebase Push Notification and display it in your Android Activity?

Tags: java, android

Sorry for this noob question, I'm new to android development. I'm currently working on a project that need to send a push notification to an android device where my app is installed. I already done this by following the quick-start tutorial by firebase and got successfully received the notification on my device.

Question: How can I retrieve the message sent by the server and display that message to my Android Activity? Thanks in advance.

Heres my code. **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    /*
    * Get the data from push notification and display it in TextView
    * */

    tv.setText("Message retrieve from Push Notification");

}
```

and this is my **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

//This method is only generating push notification
//It is same as we did in earlier posts
public void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", messageBody);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    Uri defaultSoundUri =  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Peoplelink Push Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Hi, can anyone help me with tihs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want send a mesage the your FirebaseMessagingService for your Android Activity. You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). An android optimized event bus que simplifies communication between Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc. Less code, better quality.

Add the EventBus to your build.gradle file

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Register your **MainActivity.java** and create onMessageEvent method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(String message) {
    textView.setText(message);
};
```

And use `EventBus.getDefault().post()` in your **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

Comment: Please add a few more details to your post in case the link you provide ever changes.

Comment: @dckuehn Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send some additional message (other than the one showed on notification), you can set the message in the fields under **Advanced options -> Custom data** on the firebase console.

For example, put **message** as the key and **message value** as the value.

After you putting it, the data will be sent to the device and will be passed to the activity that you set in the notification intent, through the intent extras.

Thus, to get the data, add this code on the activity onCreate:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    tv.setText(extras.getString("message", "empty message"));
}
```

The message will be showed if it set properly.